# Intel MKL in-place real-to-real transforms not possible?

Tags: c++, fft, intel-mkl

I am trying to learn how to use Intel's Math Kernel Library (MKL) to compute in-place FFTs of periodic real data. There are examples of not-in-place real-to-complex transforms and my guess at what should work for in-place real-to-real transforms does not reproduce correct results.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cmath>
#include <mkl.h>

#define TwoPI 6.2831853071795864769

/* define a periodic function */
void initialize(float* data, float* copy, const long size)
{
    const double k = TwoPI/cbrt(size);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        data[i] = cos(k*i);
        copy[i] = data[i];
    }
}

int main()
{
    const long fft_size = 1024;
    const long num_fft  = pow(fft_size,2);
    const long size     = pow(fft_size,3);

    DFTI_DESCRIPTOR_HANDLE handle = nullptr;

    /* configure a single-precision, real, 1-dimensional FFT of desired size */
    DftiCreateDescriptor(&handle, DFTI_SINGLE, DFTI_REAL, 1, (MKL_LONG)fft_size);
    DftiSetValue(handle, DFTI_NUMBER_OF_TRANSFORMS, num_fft);
    DftiSetValue(handle, DFTI_INPUT_DISTANCE, fft_size);
    DftiSetValue(handle, DFTI_OUTPUT_DISTANCE, fft_size);
    DftiSetValue(handle, DFTI_PLACEMENT, DFTI_INPLACE);
    DftiCommitDescriptor(handle);

    /* prepare the data */
    float *data = (float*) mkl_malloc( sizeof(float)*size, 32 );
    float *copy = (float*) mkl_malloc( sizeof(float)*size, 32 );
    initialize(data, copy, size);

    /* compute the forward transform */
    DftiComputeForward(handle, data);

    /* free resources */
    DftiFreeDescriptor(&handle);
    mkl_free(data);
    mkl_free(copy);

    return 0;
}
```

So, what is the solution? Is it not possible? Do I always have to deal with not-in-place real-to-complex transforms and allocate memory separately for the complex output?

Comment: I believe FFT is inplace in the standard implementation. It's is complex (on both sides). The FFT of a real vector will always be complex. The fact that the input only has 1/2 the numbers (all imaginary parts are set to zero) of the output is compensated by the fact that 1/2 the data of the output are symmetric (no new information) to the other half.

Comment: @roadrunner66 Exactly. It’s a waste of resource having to allocate twice as much memory than what is essential. So, are you confirming that what I seek is impossible with MKL?